# CSS 3 animation not working when width or height is provided

Tags: css, css-animations

I apply width-transition on a div element and the animation on it works perfectly.
But providing height and width to the same div in CSS prevents the animation. What am I missing?

On hover, neither color nor animation changes. How do I provide common styling for all divs:

1. Default styling
2. Styling on hover

[JS Fiddle sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesh_Sasidharan/6Dk4D/205/), and snippet here:

```
#div2 {

/*Un-commenting the below part, fails the animation assigned to this div
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
*/
    -webkit-transition:width 3s;
    background-color:blue;
}

div {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s;
}

 #div1 {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
}
#div2 {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
}
div:hover {
    width:300px;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is because of the selector's [specifity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). It's not really due to having a `width` or `height`, rather than they are in a rule that is more specific and thus has priority.

In your particular case, a rule with an ID takes precedence over a rule with an element (`DIV` tag) and pseudo-selector (`:hover`).

Lets consider first the case where the ID `width` is commented out. the `width` that will be used for `div2`, the blue one, could come from these rules:

- **div** → width:100px
- **div:hover** → width:300px

When the user is not hovering, the only rules to chose from get further reduced to:

- **div** → width:100px

And thus the browser picks that one, since the only one available. When the user hovers over the div, then we can choose between the 2 ones. Since the **div:hover** is more specific the browser chooses 300px for the value.

Let's see what happens when you un-comment `width` in `#div2`.

Now you have 3 rules to choose from.

- **div** → width:100px
- **#div2** → width:100px
- **div:hover** → width:300px

When not hovering this gets reduced to

- **div** → width:100px
- **#div2** → width:100px

and from the two the one that is more specific and wins out is `#div2` (you don't notice the difference because both have a 100px value).

When the user moves the cursor over the div and is now hovering, the browser gets to choose again from all 3 rules. This time the winner is not the ones you thought would win. Instead, `#div2` wins over the other two, even the one with the `:hover` pseudo-class, because it's more specific. That rule applies only to the element with ID `div2`, and not to all `div`s hovered on. So the value chosen for the `width` is 100px again. Hence there's no visible animation. It's because the element doesn't get a different width value.

How to fix this. If you're going to use an id to set an initial width, you'll also need to have a `#div2:hover` rule. You could modify the existing `:hover` rule such as this to avoid repetition (although in more complex situations you might not want to duplicate all the properties of the rule, and prefer to have 2 separate `:hover` rules):

```
div:hover , #div2:hover
{
    width:300px;
}
```

The other option is to have a `.blueDiv` rule instead of a `#div2` one, such that the rule with the class is more specific than the non-hover element one, but not more than the hover rule element one.

```
.blueDiv
{
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Even though I had got the answer by using a CLASS instead of ID to specify style, your explanation is lucid and 'more specific'.. Thumbs up..

Answer (score 0):

Since the styling in the ID overrides the styling mentioned previously for the tag, the hover also gets overridden.

If you're applying separate dimensions for the ID, you need to define its hover width separately for the ID.

Something like this in your case:

```
#div2{
width:100px;
height:50px;
-webkit-transition:width 3s;
background-color:blue;
}

#div2:hover{
    width:300px;
}
```

Example in [your modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dk4D/206/)

Comment: How can a CSS property applied to a single "Div element", override the "Div" tag itself? I want all divs to have common property -> Default styling - using div{some style}) and event styling (div:hover{some style}).. These cannot get overridden by specific element right? So if I have 100 divs, giving 100 div_xyz:hover{ wouldn't make sense}

Comment: @frozenkoi was able to explain this much better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

This is bungling, but I provided the same properties using CLASS instead of ID and the animation and property (font color, width and height) was working.

So I suppose providing properties using ID's can get overridden.. So it is always safe to use classes.